# How do I smash the p in chapter

Tags: chapters

In the table of contents, I have a green box around Chapter.  I would like to `cha\smash{p}ter` so the word is vertically more aesthetically pleasing in the box.

How do I smash the p in the definition of `\chapter{}`?

[image]

**Edit 1:**

I am using a style file made and altered by graduate students for thesis and dissertations.  I was under the impression they were using the definition of chapter in the box.

```
% ==========================================                                      
% ToC Entry modification -- green boxes.                                          
% ==========================================                                      
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
  {\vspace*{20pt}}%                                                               
  {\hspace{80pt}%                                                                 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%                               
    \draw[fill = uvmgreen, draw = uvmgreen] (-4,-.1) rectangle (-0.7,.5);%        
    \pgftext[left, x = -3.7cm, y = 0.2cm]{
      \color{white}\Large\bfseries Chapter\ \thecontentslabel};%          
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \color{uvmgreen}\large\bfseries%                                              
    \vspace{20pt}}%                                                               
  {}{}
```

But I found that they weren't from @azetina's comment.

Comment: What kind of frame are you using? Is it TikZ? If so provide a MWE?

Comment: @azetina from your comment, I found the problem.  I figured `\chapter` need to be re-defined.

Comment: I still recommend that you post your minimal working example to make your question clearer. This may be helpful to others. And in your solution below, you provide an explicit answer stating the fix and illustrating the fix of the code in your answer. Just a suggestion. Glad the questions I posed helped you as a guide to finding the solution to your question.

Comment: @azetina I planned on deleting the thread but someone made an answer so that is why I produced the correct answer.

Comment: Its azetina not azentina :-).... By the way, stating your answer is perfectly ok even when others have made attempts in answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @azetina's comment, I was able to find the problem.  I original thought that the definition of chapter would need to be redefined.  However, the box was set in TikZ where the word chapter not the definition was being used.  Therefore, I was able to smash the p easily doing `cha\smash{p}ter`.

```
% ==========================================                                      
% ToC Entry modification -- green boxes.                                          
% ==========================================                                      
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
  {\vspace*{20pt}}%                                                               
  {\hspace{80pt}%                                                                 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%                               
    \draw[fill = uvmgreen, draw = uvmgreen] (-4,-.1) rectangle (-0.7,.5);%        
    \pgftext[left, x = -3.7cm, y = 0.2cm]{
      \color{white}\Large\bfseries Cha\smash{p}ter\ \thecontentslabel};%          
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \color{uvmgreen}\large\bfseries%                                              
    \vspace{20pt}}%                                                               
  {}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
Cha\raisebox{0.3ex}{\scalebox{1}[0.75]{p}}ter
\end{document}
```

comes closer to your idea?

[image]

Comment: No.  I found the problem from @azetina's comment.